# Accessing more than one active records in action controller in rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord, actionpack

suppose I have 2 models: 1. user and 2. userProfile 
we have one-to-one relationship between 2 models. 
Then,I would like to create Usercontroller and create user with fields such as username and password in user and other details like address, mobile number,etc in userprofile.

**user_id is a foreign key in user_profile** 

Then I created new.html.erb in user a view that render all above fields in a same form.
Then how I can save the data in two different tables user and userprofile respectively.

what I tried is

 1. has_one :user_profile in *user.rb* and  belongs_to :user in *user_profile.rb*
 
 2. accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_profile in *user.rb*
user_controller:

```
     def create
       @user = User.new(params[:user])
       if @user.save
          @userprofile = @user.create_user_profile(params[:user_profile])
               redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed up!"     
       else
          render "new"
        end 
      end
```

3. Then I got error the only userid is created in user_profile and also update run to make user_id nil which can't be! so raising error:

```
Unknown column 'user_profiles.' in 'where clause': UPDATE `user_profile` 
SET `user_id` = NULL WHERE `user_profiles`.`` IS NULL
```

**so what's wrong and how to troubleshoot this?**

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `accepts_nested_fields_for` then you don't need to manage saving the UserProfile records yourself. ActiveRecord will take care of it for you.

To get this to work you need to:

1. Make sure you have `accepts_nested_fields_for :user_profile` in your User model
2. Update your app/views/users/_form.html.erb to include form elements for the UserProfile, e.g.:

   ```
   <%= f.fields_for :user_profile, @user.user_profile do |profile_form| %>
   <%= profile_form.text_field :address %>
   <%= profile_form.text_field :mobile_number %>
   <% end %>
   ```
3. Update your `UsersController#new` action to build the UserProfile for the User, e.g.

   ```
   def new
     @user = User.new
     @user.build_user_profile
     (...)
   end
   ```

For more information see the [Rails API docs covering Active Record Nested Attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html).

Comment: I followed this, now.But!, nothing is stored in a user_profile table

Comment: Check that you don't have any failing validations in your UserProfile model. If you're unsure, just disable any validations you have in that model and try.

Comment: I have not put any validations in UserProfile model right now.Is there something missing?

Comment: You could try adding `attr_accessible :user_profile_attributes` to your User model. Also check that the attributes are coming through in params[:user][:user_profile_attributes].

Comment: No this also not working and when I pass params[:user][:user_profile_attributes] it throws validation errors

Comment: Now when I pass params[:user_profile] as userprofile = user.create_user_profile(params[:userprofile]) after user.save,then the values are inserted into user_profile successfully except for it triggers update query of UPDATE `user_profiles` SET 'user_id'= NULL where 'user_profile'.' IS NULL

Comment: what I think is the either model/controller not receiving values from user_profile.